# GET PDF FROM INTERNAL STORAGE

Tags: pdf

I want to list all pdf files available in my device. But only getting images not pdf.

Comment: It requires more info to help you, add as much infos you can give us. Show us the code you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Go to terminal-
type

`cd/`

`dir /s/b /A: "*.pdf*"`
you will see all pdf in your device

Comment: @KJ not necessary.... but I used that command years ago for erasing data of application from root ...haha..

Comment: I want to get programmatically.